# To upload an Android App Bundle you must be enrolled in the Play app signing

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, google-play

I am updating the existing version of my app from my play store developer account. When I am uploading the AAB file, I get the below error:
"To upload an Android App Bundle you must be enrolled in Play app signing."

I tried play app signing in two ways. They are:

1. Tried using the existing app signing key from the Java keystore option. But, on the command prompt, when I run the command by adding the app keystore file name, alias name, and password, I get the error "Unable to export or encrypt the private key."
2. Tried using the existing app signing key from another repository option. But I'm getting "The private key was not properly encrypted or is not a type of key we support."

But, both ways, I'm getting errors. How can I fix this issue? Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to your play store account and open `App Signing` under `Set Up`.

[image]

Download the `Encryption Public Key` and `PEPK Tool` from play store. Then **open the `keystore folder` on your `command prompt`** and run the below command on it.

```
java -jar E:\pepk.jar --keystore=keystore_name.keystore --alias=alias_name --output=encrypted_private_key_path --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=E:\encryption_public_key.pem
```

**Make sure the path of `pepk.jar` and `encryption_public_key.pem` are added in the command.** Then you need to enter your `keystore password` and `alias password`. After that `encrypted_private_key_path` file will be generated and store to your keystore folder.